# Prompt Message Box when progress bar value hits 0

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I've made it so I have a progress bar which is the players health starting at 100 and going down over time via a timer. When the player health progress bar gets to 0, I want a message to come up saying "You died! Game over."

Instead of doing that, it just does that when I click it as soon as the progress bar has reached 0, due to the 'Handles PlayerHealth.Click' bit. But what do I change the PlayerHealth.Click to to make it so the message box comes up when the progress bar just hits 0, without having to click it?

I can't find the right thing in the intellisense list. Or is there a better method?

Here's the piece of code in question :

```
Private Sub AttackButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles AttackButton.Click
    PlayerHealthTimer.Start()
    EnemyHealth.Increment(-2)
End Sub

Private Sub PlayerHealthTimer_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PlayerHealthTimer.Tick
    PlayerHealth.Increment(-2)
End Sub

Private Sub PlayerHealth_Value(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PlayerHealth.Click
    If PlayerHealth.Value = 0 Then
        MsgBox("You died! Game over.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Ignore the middle sub.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fires on click because you have the MessageBox in the Sub that is handling the click method.

You may actually want to use the middle sub you said to ignore :). That one handles the logic on each tick.

```
Private Sub PlayerHealthTimer_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PlayerHealthTimer.Tick
    PlayerHealth.Increment(-2)
    if PlayerHealth.Value = 0 Then
      MsgBox("You died! Game Over.")
      ''Then make sure to stop the timer
      PlayerHealthTimer.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That seems to have done half the job, thank you! But now although the message box now opens, there's about 30 of them! My code looks exactly like what you copied. And each extra time I click the attack button after closing all the extra message boxes, tons of them open again.

Comment: @Laurence Chaffey When you hit your "attack button" it restarts your timer. Restarting the timer is going to cause it to trigger again.

Comment: @LaurenceChaffey You are seeing multiple message boxes because the code only stops the timer after the message box is closed. The timer will keep ticking and creating message boxes until you close one of them.

Answer (score 1):

you can just use condition like

```
if PlayerHealth.value<=0 then
'place a message box or other way to show info message
end if
```